# Counting sum of values, based on unique values

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am not sure if the title is clear enough, so I'll do my best to explain what I want and what the problem is.

**What I have**
I have a graph that get's filled with data from a query.
Every day of the month has a value that is grouped by day, for example:
day 1 = 5, day 2 = 6, day 3 = 8 etc.

This works with the following code, for 1 subscription:

```
data_usage = DataUsage.objects \
    .filter(subscription_id=subscription_id) \
    .filter(created_at__month=today.month) \
    .annotate(
        created_date=TruncDay('created_at')
    ).values('created_date') \
    .annotate(
        subscription_id=Max('subscription_id'),
        data_usage=Max('data_usage'),
        created_at=Max('created_at')
    ).values(
        'subscription_id',
        'data_usage',
        'created_at'
    )
```

The image below is a correctly filled graph with the code above:
[image]

**What I need**
I need this same graph but this time with the values from every subscription.
So basically the code has to give me the same output, but with the sum of 'data_usage' of all subscriptions for that day.
Only the highest and thus latest value for every subscription should be used.

I have tried 10's of solutions that did not work for me, the current code does not work:

```
data_usage = DataUsage.objects \
    .filter(created_at__month=today.month) \
    .annotate(
        created_date=TruncDay('created_at')
    ).values('created_date') \
    .annotate(
        subscription_id=Max('subscription_id'),
        data_usage=Sum('data_usage'),
        created_at=Max('created_at')
    ).values(
        'data_usage',
        'created_at'
    )
```

[image]

**What's wrong with the data?**
There should be a total of around 800 GB.
It's way over that value, it seems to just count everything..

**In short what I need**
I need the sum of data_usage, grouped by day and filled with the highest/latest value of the subscription.
This should give me the correct total data usage per day.

DataUsage model as requested:

```
class DataUsage(models.Model):
    objects = DataUsageQuerySet.as_manager()

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subscription_id = models.ForeignKey('subscriptions.Subscription', db_column='subscription_id', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Becomes subscription_id
    data_usage = models.FloatField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Please share your models. Likely it makes a `JOIN` on both the subscription *and* the `data_usage`, hence that means that the two joins act as a multiplier of each other. So if there are two subscriptions for that record, the `data_usage` is counted twice.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem
Thanks for your answer.  
subscription_id is a ForeignKey.   
Per DataUsage object there is only 1 subscription.

Comment: can you please share your models...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem

Check the opening post.
The subscriptions_model has no link to the DataUsage model. If there were a weird join, the first example would not have worked.